# Splitting a column into 2 other cells

Tags: html

[image]

Are there any other ways available to split a column into 2 columns rather than this method. For an example I need to first check whether the first column can be divided into 2 while it is creating. After creating the first Adress column including Address1 and Address2 then I should create the Name Column.

```
<table border="1">
<tr><td colspan="2">Address</td><td rowspan="2">Name</td></tr>
<tr><td>Address1</td><td>Address2</td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</table>
```

This create the table what I need. Bt not exactly through the way I need. Coz in my real question I exactly don't know the number columns will be....

Comment: If the table is generated dynamically server-side then let the server side script count the number of columns. What language are you using?

Comment: 819x460px just for that image? ಠ_ಠ

Comment: I'm creating the table in PHP

Comment: PHP; like any other programming language, has `if else`constructions, that should be enough (if adress.length > 1 then, add 2 columns)... You can also pass the parameters from PHP to Javascript and generate the table client-side...